# How to prevent twisted exception python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, twisted

I am using

```
scrapy shell https://www.mon-panier-bio.com/distributeur/local/ou-trouver-panier-bio-france/
```

which results

```
twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone:
Connection was closed cleanly.>,
<twisted.python.failure.Failuretwisted.web.http._DataLoss: >]
Traceback(most recent call last):File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", 
line 11, in <module>sys.exit(execute())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py"
,line 143, in execute  _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd,args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 
89, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 50, in run
shell.start(url=url, spider=spider)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 
45, in start self.fetch(url, spider)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 
90, in fetch reactor, self._schedule, request, spider)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 
122, in blockingCallFromThread
result.raiseException()
File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed: 
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure 
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed 
cleanly.>, <twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.web.http._DataLoss: 
>]
```

Guide me what should I to prevent from this exception. I am using scrapy 1.1.1 and twisted 16.3.0

Comment: See [related issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2586). Scrapy 1.4 will have a setting to not fail on this kind of data loss. It's called [`DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/settings.html#download-fail-on-dataloss) but it will be available only from Scrapy 1.4.0 (you can use scrapy master branch for now)

Comment: @paultrmbrth any solution for scrapy 1.1?

Comment: One option is to clone scrapy's repo from GitHub and cherry-pick the changes from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2590 into the 1.1 branch.